# Create a customized membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Need to create a customized membership with database and web application in ASP.net mvc.

Any instruction how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the official doc is a good starting point: [Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx).

You can also have a look at the standard sql server membership using .NET Reflector. I found it the best way to learn how you are supposed to implement it.